# Fixed nav bar is transparent, would like for it to be opaque

Tags: css, position, nav, fixed

I am trying to complete a Technical Documentation project for FCC. I'm supposed to fix the nav bar, however, no matter if I change the background color its stays transparent so that the words behind it show through. I guess I am also looking to wrap the main around the fixed nav bar

```
    #navbar {
    position: fixed ;
    min-width: 250px;
    border-right: solid 2px black;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
  }
    #navbar ul {
    padding: 0px;
  }
    #navbar li {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
    #main-doc {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
  }
```

Comment: Please post the source code in code snippet so that we can understand what you want.

Comment: I suggest you to study more on the use of positions: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp